# Trying to understand closures

Tags: go

Sorry, still a newb in Go. I am trying to write a closure:

https://play.golang.org/p/qz-8WFh0mv

```
package main

import "log"


func myfunc(a int) bool{
  func otherfunc(b int) bool{
    return false
  }
  log.Println(otherfunc(2))
  return true
}

func main() {
        myfunc(1)
    log.Println("here")
}
```

A similar function in Python would work. Why doesn't this work in Go?

Comment: What exactly is not working here? btw. you define two arguments a and b but never use them.

Comment: What the exact problem you facing?

Comment: @AjayPandya I have the code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the inner func as a local variable. Try this

```
func myfunc(a int) bool {
  otherfunc := func(b int) bool {
    return false
  }
  log.Println(otherfunc(2))
  return true
}
```

Btw. `otherfunc := func(b int) bool {` is shorthand for `var otherfunc func(int) bool = func(b int) bool {`

Look at these examples

https://gobyexample.com/closures

https://gobyexample.com/variables